# defining callback functions in javascript for all event types

Tags: javascript, events, callback

Developing page to test how events are fire in a browser. I am trying to create a script that logs event types as the happen on a target div regardless of the event type. 
To do this I have written code that first finds all event types supported by the window. This is based on code found [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/08/17/javascript-events-responding-user/).

It then tries to attach all of these events to the target div. here named 'testbed'
As console.log(i) counts all the way to zero I presume that the handles are all successfully added.
Therefore I assume that I have not worked out the best way to add function callback

When I load this page in Google chrome I see a large red div. 
The console correctly displays first a list of events including 'onclick'
The console the counts from 70 to 0 indicating 70 events added.
It finally declares all events added.
When I click on the div nothing further is registered in the console.

So the question is, if the function `logType` is passed to `setEventListeners` which in turn hands it to the individual `addEventListener` and this is applied to every event type why does clicking on the div in question not cause any log to the console?

complete code below

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<style>
#testbed {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='testbed'>

</div>
<script>
    var myApp = {
        init: function () {
            this.getSupportedOccurances(window);
            var testbed = document.getElementById('testbed');
            this.setEventListeners(testbed, this.occurances, this.logType);
        },
        occurances: [],

        getSupportedOccurances: function (target) {
            var i = '', occurances = this.occurances;
            for (i in target) {
                if ( /^on/.test(i)) { occurances[occurances.length] = i; }
            }
            console.log(occurances);
        },
        setEventListeners: function(target, eventList, callback) {
            var i = eventList.length-1;
            if (i > -1) {
                console.log('adding');

                do {
                    console.log(i);
                    target.addEventListener(eventList[i], callback);
                }
                while (--i >=0);
            }
            console.log('Event Listeners added');
        },
        logType: function (event) {
            console.log(event.type);
        }
    }
myApp.init();
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: so what's the question?

Comment: sorry let me try and clarify

Comment: Does that better explain?

Comment: This will only work in IE i guess since you're adding the handlers to "on{EventName}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `addEventListener` you must remove the `on` prefix from the event name.

You can do this with:

```
occurances[occurances.length] = i.substring(2);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/3u6eQ/